# Printing non string values in haskell

Tags: haskell

How can i print a value that is a non string type to console? The type is below.

```
data Expr = Var String | Con Bool | Uno Unop Expr | Duo Duop Expr Expr | List [Expr]
 deriving Show
```

I have a list of the above type values and i would like to print them to screen each on a separate line( not the classic list view). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `print` on each element of your list:

```
mapM' print exprs
```

Comment: how about a list of lists? I would like to print each individual from a list within a list. Like [[1,2,3],[3,4,5]] . I want 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: @vasiliuiorgu If you still want each entry on its own line (not caring which entry was in which sublist), you can just `concat` it first.